# Static partial-order reduction on a given state space

Tags: formal-verification, model-checking

Most papers about partial-order reduction assume that the system to be analyzed is given as a set of processes with some composition operator. This makes much sense, since you do not want to compute the state space first, and then to reduce it using partial-order reduction.

But, assuming that you already given a flat state space, can you still reduce it using partial-order reduction? I was thinking that this should be possible using a modified DFS. Some properties can be checked locally, and the cycle condition can be taken into account by using the information you have about states on the stack.

Is there any paper or other reference where such an algorithm is presented?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible. As you described, the algorithm is very similar to the traditional approach. The only difference is the way information about independence of actions is gathered. Conceptually this is all pretty straightforward. Therefore, I don't think there are any papers on such an algorithm.

For you use-case, bisimulation minimisation is more useful. Baier and Katoen give a great introduction in their book "Principles of Model Checking". The state-of-the-art is described in "Paige and Tarjan - Three partition refinement algorithms" for strong bisimulation and "Groote and Wijs - An O(m log n) Algorithm for Stuttering Equivalence and Branching Bisimulation" for branching bisimulation.